# SilverStripe actions on home page return 404

Tags: silverstripe

I have a page set up with an action as is usual, however when I use this page as the home page (url segment is 'home') the action (e.g. http://{BaseHref}/someaction) returns 404. How do I get SilverStripe to recognize home page actions?

```
class MyPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    private static $allowed_actions = array('someaction');

    public function someaction() {
        die('never get here');
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure your home page is of type `MyPage`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in SilverStripe, routing for actions on pages always works the same way:

```
$baseURL/$URLSegment/Action
```

this means that if you do `/someaction` it will not look for an action, instead it will look for a Page with an URLSegment of `someaction`.

so if you want to call an action on your homepage, you have to include the URLSegment.

that is usually `/home/someaction`
however, I strongly recommend using the `$Link` method.

```
$Link('someaction') // will output /home/someaction
// alternatively you can also do $Link/someaction
```

also note:

- private static variables like `$allowed_actions` are cached, you have to flush (visit `/?flush=1`) to get SilverStripe to reload that cache.
- `$BaseHref` is deprecated, please use `$baseURL` or `$absoluteBaseURL` instead.